# Under what rule of usage does this semicolon in the example sentence fall?

Tags: commas, semicolons

I noticed the following sentence, taken from Mark Twain's "The Awful German Language:"

> *Fifthly, I would do away with those long compounded words; or require the speaker to deliver them in sections, with intermissions for refreshments.*

What is the grammatical function of the semicolon here? I would have expected a comma to be appropriate here, as to me it coordinates a dependent clause, and that would be solely under the jurisdiction of a comma, as I understood.

I thought semicolons were for replacing conjunctions between independent clauses or avoiding confusion with commas when writing a list that requires commas for one of the points within.

Thank you!

Comment: Semicolons are full stops. They go after complete sentences just like periods; any text following a semicolon -- which may contain commas, or other punctuation -- is considered extra information. As [Lewis Thomas](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/punctuation.html) put it, "The semicolon tells you that there is still some question about the preceding full sentence; something needs to be added".

Answer (score 1):

The use of a semicolon as a 'super-comma' to collate elements in a sub-grouped or other complex list with more clarity is probably accepted by many English writers nowadays. Thus

> The groups he chose were Ali, Betty, and Clive; Dwayne, Elly and
> Frances; Geoff, Habib and Ian; and Jasmine, Kelly and Lily.

For other examples, see [this article by Lola Taylor at Scribophile](http://www.scribophile.com/academy/correct-semicolon-usage) (which also mentions the changes in attitude to the acceptable use of the semicolon).

Taylor (op cit) even mentions the possibility of replacing a comma by a semicolon + conjunction. She gives an example with *but*; I'd say that sentences starting with *and* might also still be considered reasonably idiomatic. However, using a semicolon as a super-comma in other situations (here, to signal a more major sentence division than the other two commas do, with the addition of *or*) is highly unusual to  non-standard nowadays. 'The very term 'super-comma' is restricted to the use in lists of subdivided items. A dash (or full stop, and yes, a sentence beginning with 'Or') would be used today.

Comment: Thank you for the link! That's the closest thing to an explanation I've found. It must be under rule #2. Interesting. I suppose I could actually make use of that, since there isn't a good replacement; and even a dash doesn't feel like it brings the same connotation in the flow of the sentence.